# Angular - Function undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm programming a web application based on Angular.
When I run it with Bower it all works just fine, except for one part.
I'm using the exact very syntax as with other modules, but can't figure out why with this one it doesn't find the controller function.

providers.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.hostels.providers', [

        ]);
})();
```

providers.config.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.hostels.providers')
        .config(moduleConfig);

    /* @ngInject */
    function moduleConfig($translatePartialLoaderProvider, $stateProvider, triMenuProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/hostels/providers');

        $stateProvider
        .state('triangular.admin-default.providers-new', {
            url: '/provider/',
            templateUrl: 'app/hostels/providers/new/new.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'NewProviderController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            data: {
                layout: {
                    contentClass: 'full-image-background mb-bg-fb-16 background-overlay-static',
                    innerContentClass: 'overlay-gradient-20'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('triangular.admin-default.providers-newbed', {
            url: '/bed',
            templateUrl: 'app/hostels/providers/newbed/newbed.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'NewBedController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('triangular.admin-default.providers-list', {
            url: '/providers',
            templateUrl: 'app/hostels/providers/listprov/list.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'ListprovController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('triangular.admin-default.providers-edit', {
            url: '/provider/:index',
            templateUrl: 'app/hostels/providers/edit/edit.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'EditController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });

        triMenuProvider.addMenu({
            name: 'MENU.PROVIDERS.PROVIDERS',
            icon: 'zmdi zmdi-hotel',
            type: 'dropdown',
            priority: 4.1,
            children: [{
                name: 'MENU.PROVIDERS.NEW',
                state: 'triangular.admin-default.providers-new',
                type: 'link'
            },{
                name: 'MENU.PROVIDERS.NEWBED',
                state: 'triangular.admin-default.providers-newbed',
                type: 'link'
            },{
                name: 'MENU.PROVIDERS.LIST',
                state: 'triangular.admin-default.providers-list',
                type: 'link'
            }]
        });
    }

})();
```

listprov/listprov.controller.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.hostels.providers')
        .controller('ListprovController', ListprovController);

        function ListprovController ($scope, $http, $location, APP, ApiResourceProvider, $log ) {
            var vm = this;
            $log.log('Providers list');
        }

    }
);
```

When I run the app, I get a console error sayin' that ListprovController is not a function, and got undefined.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is Node.js relevant here? All that you show here is a client side code.

Comment: You aren't calling your function expression in the last file (You are missing `()`)

Comment: Tried that, but still returns the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    var ListprovController = function () { };
```

instead of

```
    function ListprovController() { }
```

Comment: Tried and still the same... Anyway what gets my attention is that the other modules syntax is the exact same as the one I use with this module. And if I replace the controller name for a function, it works, but It doesn't with the controller name. Any other ideas?

Comment: I mean, if I replace the controller name in the state declaration

Comment: If you indeed invoke the iife, maybe you didn't include your controller JS file in your html code.

You don't close your function with a semicolon. Not sure what that results in with strict mode.

Comment: Added the semicolon, and now it invokes a function from another module!

Comment: I see now that function declarations shouldn't be closed with a semicolon, only function expressions. 

Anyway, this means you did include the file indeed. I have no clue what could be wrong otherwise.

Comment: Got it! It was the file's name. I have a function that automatically loads all modules files, but I have to name the files propperly. I just had to change providers.js into providers.module.js. Thanks for your help anyway!